# Python remove all child elements except one

Tags: python, xml

have to remove all child elements except one (SimpleData name="NAME") .

So i would want to keep .

```
<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#osa_20140910_areas">
    <SimpleData name="gml_id">219</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ID">219</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="CODE">520</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="DISTRICT">102</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="STOR_DISTRICT">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="COUNTY">91</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="WHOLE_CODE">911102520.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NAME">Calgary</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: which one you like to keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Element.remove()` from [lxml](http://lxml.de/index.html) to delete individual elements.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.XML('''<Placemark>
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
<ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#osa_20140910_areas">
    <SimpleData name="gml_id">219</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="ID">219</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="CODE">520</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="DISTRICT">102</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="STOR_DISTRICT">1</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="COUNTY">91</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="WHOLE_CODE">911102520.000000000000000</SimpleData>
    <SimpleData name="NAME">Calgary</SimpleData>
</SchemaData></ExtendedData>
</Placemark>''')
print tree
for simple_data in tree.xpath('//SimpleData[@name!="NAME"]'):
  simple_data.getparent().remove(simple_data)

print etree.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: Thanks.. How about reading from an xml file? I tried using minidom.parse to parse the xml file but doesnt seem to work

Comment: getting error XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandate value for attribute instance, line 1, column 34

Comment: 1) To parse a file, replace `etree.XML(...)` with `etree.parse('filename.xml')`, replacing the file name, of course. 2) My example uses `lxml`. I don't have an example using `minidom`. If `minidom` is a requirement, please add that information to the question. 3) `XMLSyntaxErrror` means that input file is not valid XML. The error in your XML can be found in the 34th character of the 1st line of your XML text.